# Subset of discrete and closed subset is also discrete and closed?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I came upon the following question (probably trivial...):

> Let $X$ be a topological space Suppose $N \subseteq M \subseteq X$ and $M$ is closed and discrete in $X$. Then is it true that $N$ is closed and discrete in $X$?

---

My thoughts:  I believe the statement is *true*.

Let $a \in N \subseteq M$, Then exists nhood $U_a \cap N = U_a \cap M = \{ a \}$. Thus $N$ is discrete. Suppose $N$ has an accumulation point; exists $x \in X$ such that $\{ x_n \} \subseteq N \subseteq M$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$. Then $x$ is also an accumulation point of $M$. As $M$ is closed, $x \in M$, contradicting discreteness. Hence, $N$ has no accumulation point, and is therefore closed.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Your proof is enough rigorous and quite good. Well done!

Comment: What definition of accumulation point do you use?

Comment: $x$ is an accumulation point of $N$ if for all nhood $U$ of $x$, $U \setminus \{x \} \cap N \not= \emptyset$? I am quite confused by the comments below, I think I have confused accumulation point with sequential convergence which is not true in general, the proof of William Elliot (which I guess is right?) is closer to my original intention.

Comment: Good proof. For $N$ being closed you can also say that every $ p\in X$ has a nbhd $U_p$ with $U_p\cap M\subset\{p\}.$... So if $p \in X$ \ $N$ then $U_p\cap N=U_p\cap (M\cap N)=$ $(U_p\cap M )\cap N$  $\subset \{p\}\cap N=\phi.$

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that $\{ x_n \}$ is not eventually constant:

[...] exists $x \in X$ such that $\{ x_n \}$ not eventually constant, $\{ x_n \}\subseteq N \subseteq M$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$.

Otherwise you cannot conclude that $x$ is also an accumulation point of $M$, but only that $x$ is a limit point of $M$ (that is, isolated points are included).

Moreover, note that $\{ x_n \}$ could not be a sequence, but it is certainly a net, because you are talking here about topological space in general and not for instance about a second-countable topological space where sequence convergence is sufficient to caracterize set closure. So it would be better to write it as $\{ x_\alpha \}$, $\alpha \in A$, where $A$ is a directed set

Comment: Actually you need not and should not assume that $x_n$ is eventually constant. Actually since it's discrete spaces you will have $x_j=x$ always eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed N is not closed.  Then some x not in N with for all open U nhood x,
U cap N is not empty.  Since M is closed, x in M, which contradicts that
M is discrete.

Answer (score 0):

The part that shows that $N$ is discrete is OK, but the second part is a bit confused to the end.

There's actually no contradiction in $x\in M$ (actually that follows from the fact that $M$ is closed and $x$ is a limit ponit of $M$). What you instead use is the fact that if $x_j\to x$ in a discrete space you must have an $N$ so that $x_j=x$ for every $j>N$. This means that if $x$ is a limit point of $N$ you have that $x_j=x$ (since it converges in $M$) eventually and since $x_j\in N$ we have that $N$ contains the limit point (and that $N$ contains all of it's limit points is the same as $N$ is closed).

To see that $x_j=x$ always eventually follows from the definition since there exists a nhood of $x$ that contains only $x$ and eventually $x_j$ must remain in that nhood.

Comment: Indeed, also the second part of the proof by CWL is clear and needed (though with the correction reported in my answer) and the contradiction of $x \in M$ is correct, because CWL is proving that $N$ does not have accumulation points because $M$ cannot have any. Instead in what you say, you are trying to prove the same thing as an implication of the discreteness on N (as if the fact that M is closed is superfluous). You can have discrete sets that are not closed. Again the question is about (general) topological spaces.

Comment: That may depend on what definition of accumulation point he is using, but those I've seen the second part of the proof is confused. The definition of closed is that it's to include all it's accumulation poinst which means that it can have accumulation points. There's no contradiction in concluding that $x\in M$.

Comment: In my proof I do use that $M$ is closed since $x$ is a limit point of $M$ and because $M$ is closed $x\in M$, I then use the discreteness to show that $x_j=x$ always eventually.

Comment: As you see you don't need that correction to show that $x\in M$, just that $M$ is closed and $x$ is a limit point of $N$ and therefore $M$.